# UWP BackgroundTransfer (CreateDownload / GetCurrentDownloadsAsync) Exception

Tags: c#, uwp, background-transfer

I am using [BackgroundTransfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers) API for UWP and during my development I achieve much more than the limit (200) of transfer, until now this not become a problem because windows management cancel the transfers over the limit. But now, something occurs that I never can create a new download by **BackgroundDownloader().CreateDownload()** or call **BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()** because this exception always occur:

> WinRT information: Quota for maximum number of concurrent operations
>   exceeded. Wait for an operation to complete before starting new ones.

I already tried many things to solve this problem with NO success:

- Wait a long time (days) to finish those lost background downloads
- Reboot PC many times
- Terminate / Reset / Uninstall / Reinstall my App (Settings -> App & features)
- Run Troubleshooter for Windows Store Apps
- Windows Update
- Clean all references of my app from Register (regedit)

I really do not want to format/reinstall my Windows 10. :(

Anyone with some idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How about using a different package name? Then to the OS it is a completely new app. Still it sounds strange that system keeps track of the unfinished downloads even if you have uninstalled an app.

Comment: Ohh great tip! I changed the Package name and it work as expected, when I turn back the name to original package name the problem solved!! 
Thank you very much @kennyzx!!

Comment: Welcome. I will provide the verified solution as an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason, the registration of the app is kept somewhere and the app cannot be  completely removed, so you get the exception even after uninstalling the app. This is likely to be an issue of the OS or Visual Studio.

Since the package name is unique for every app, so if you change its package name, it becomes a brand new app to the OS. Then it should start working again.

> And it works after reverting back to the original package name.