# UWP BackgroundDownloader (CreateDownload) Exception

Tags: c#, exception, uwp

When calling method **BackgroundDownloader().CreateDownload()** as **operation = downloader.CreateDownload(url, outputFile);** I got exception: *Quota for maximum number of concurrent operations exceeded*, but this exception happens on some devices (it happened sometimes). I already read this post [UWP BackgroundTransfer (CreateDownload / GetCurrentDownloadsAsync) Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262128/uwp-backgroundtransfer-createdownload-getcurrentdownloadsasync-exception) , I see the solution worked, but I think this is a tricky workaround and I want to ask Is there any **real solution** (using code to handle) for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you create many concurrent operations, you can try to catch this exception and wait for other operation to complete, after that you create your new download operation.

Comment: Thanks Liu, I sounds weird, because this happened for the first time when I create a new background downloader and no other one created before, and how to check when other concurrent operation is complete?

Comment: It is strange that the issue happens on the first time you launch the app and create a new background downloader. Do you alway get this issue? What is your device OS version and the app target and min version? Could you try to conclude them and help me see this issue?

Comment: yes, the device OS version is 1803, target version = min version = 16299. This issue still happens when I uninstall app and install again.

Comment: Could you try to create a repro sample to help me see the issue?